# {Solved}(Camera Troubles) Scene Disappears After Using Camera

Tags: camera

I'm mildly new to blender, but I've been having a bit of trouble with the camera. You see, I have my scene set up perfectly fine: [image]

However, Clicking on the camera and pressing Numpad 0, this is what happens:  [image]

It has been super frustrating, as it's been like this for days. If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please don't cut your images so tight. In that camera view please show the whole interface. Do you have more than one camera in the scene? Is the camera in the same layer as the objects?

Comment: I do believe so, I'll redo the pictures. Is there another way to access the camera without the numpad?

Comment: In the lower screenshot you are on a layer that has no objects or cameras.

Comment: Oh wow! *facepalm* it works when I used the menu to get to the camera... that's strange, but at least it works. Thanks for your patience, sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: You mean that when you select View > Camera from the menu you get a different result than when you press num0? Because that should not happen. Can you check again?